# Can I transpile TypeScript to ES6 if I only use it with Node?

Tags: node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6

I writing a new App running on Node. The code will only ever run on a Node-server, so browser-compatibility is not an issue. The code-base is written in TypeScript.

In my `tsconfig.json` I have the following options set for the compiler:

```
{
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",

    "sourceMap": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true
  }
}
```

**Note** that I'm targeting ES6 but exporting CommonJS modules!

The code produced by tsc (version 2.1.4) runs fine on Node (version 6.9.1), as far as I have tested it. Also, consulting [node.green](http://node.green/) shows that most ES5 and ES6 features are implemented in Node.

Sadly, I can't find any information or official recommendations as to what JavaScript version should be used with Node. As far as I can see, there is nothing preventing me from using ES6.

**My question**: Can I **reliably** use the generated ES6 code with Node?

Comment: As long as you only use ES6 features that are supported by your Node version, yes, it should be fine.

Comment: @JoeClay Is there any lint functionality that I can use to check for these?

Comment: If you've already checked node.green, why the question? Yes, Node fully supports ES6 (with the exception of ES6 modules).

Comment: @estus well, aside from features being implemented, there could be other things that might cause problems. I couldn't find anything along the lines of "works fine, mind the gaps". I just didn't want it to fail in production later, that's why I asked.

Comment: Fortunately, all 'other things' can be described as features, too. So no, there should be no unexpected problems. But there may be ones if ES6-specific code is transpiled to ES5.

Comment: @estus if you add what you said here as an answer, I will accept it

Comment: Sure. It should be also noticed that if the app has common parts between server and client side, they should be written with ES5 target in mind (no native object subclassing, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All ES6 implementation nuances can be described as features. That's what was done at [node.green](http://node.green).

With the exception of ES6 modules, Node 6+ fully (99% compatibility, with some minor discrepancies) supports ES6.

So no, there should be no unexpected problems. But there may be ones if ES6-specific code is transpiled to ES5, so ES5 target will likely cause troubles, on the other hand.

Answer (score 0):

This is what the Node.js site has to say:

> All ECMAScript 2015 (ES6) features are split into three groups for shipping, staged, and in progress features:
>
> - All shipping features, which V8 considers stable, are turned on by default on Node.js and do NOT require any kind of runtime flag.
> - Staged features, which are almost-completed features that are not considered stable by the V8 team, require a runtime flag: --harmony.
> - In progress features can be activated individually by their respective harmony flag, although this is highly discouraged unless for testing purposes. Note: these flags are exposed by V8 and will potentially change without any deprecation notice.

Read more [here](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/es6/)

Comment: I read that and also checked the resulting table on node.green. The question is, are there any (other) reasons not to do it?